# How do I prevent dougnuts deflating when moving them into the pan?

Tags: baking, non-stick

I find that each time I cook dougnuts, as I slide them off the tray into the oil pan, they deflate a fair bit, and sometimes crinkle up. How do I effectively prevent this, and keep them gorgeous and fluffy?

I imagine the problem is twofold - not making them stick in the first place, and also maybe using a specific implement to slide them off. Any ideas are appreciated, and will be tested!

Edit for details: I use a non-stick tray - they come off it easily, but the deflation is the real problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps proofing them too long, so that they loose their stability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect @Stephie is correct in thinking they may be over proofed. Having said that, you could try the method that is used when making crullers.

Place shaped donuts on parchment paper that has been sprayed with non-stick cooking spray.

Cut the paper into individual squares (each donut should have enough space to raise without expanding off the paper). Let raise.

When ready to fry, just slip the paper with donut into your oil, it should release right away and you can remove the paper from the oil with tongs.

Here is a link to [a video showing how it's done with crullers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiNXOp0UA8k).You can skip the first 3 minutes that shows the mixing and piping of the crullers.

Comment: That's genius! Makes perfect sense, thank you so much. I have a feeling over proofing was a contributor last time, but this time I ensured I didn't prove too long, and they still shrunk a little whilst transferring. Next time, I'll definitely be adding this strategy into the mix!